# didFinishLaunchingWithOptions not called but app is running and faced with crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I had seen lots of iPhone apps that running on iPad with buttons name `x1` and `x2`. I have an application that first I developed it as a `universal` app but now I changed it to `iPhone` and expect to run it on iPad with that `x1` and `x2` style but when I run it on the iPad I see this core data error:

```
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Settings''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x187b6659c 0x1987cc0e4 0x18781d278 0x100110984 0x100110ab8 0x100110494 0x1000f4cdc 0x1000d2644 0x1000d2720 0x18c835544 0x18c318844 0x18c3187b0 0x18c834fbc 0x18c832ce8 0x18c344788 0x18c5af238 0x18c5aecec 0x18c5aec44 0x18c5a2578 0x18c5a1fe0 0x18fdb1edc 0x18fdc162c 0x187b1ea28 0x187b1db30 0x187b1c154 0x187a490a4 0x18c3833c8 0x18c37e3c0 0x100108098 0x198e3aa08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

It is working right on iPhone but I see this crash in iPad?

I have this code in my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions that initialize core data

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


    //--------- Initialize appearance and database ------------//
    [[BRCoreRepository instance] initializeDatabase:self.managedObjectContext];

// Othe ui codes is here

    return YES;

}
```

In iPad version  the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`  it is not calling so the app do not pass the initialize phase of core data and the before showing the viewController it crashes.

Please notice that it is working perfect in iPhone and the problem exist in iPad

This is the stack trace in iPad simulator:

```
    *** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d11dd85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c280deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreData                            0x000000010cc6448b +[NSEntityDescription entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:] + 251
    3   APMB                                0x000000010bb8f0e4 -[BRSettingsRepository getAllRowsInSettings] + 100
    4   APMB                                0x000000010bb8f24b -[BRSettingsRepository loadDataFromDB] + 43
    5   APMB                                0x000000010bb8ec3c +[BRSettingsRepository instance] + 332
    6   APMB                                0x000000010bb7333e -[BRLanguageManager language] + 46
    7   APMB                                0x000000010bb4e084 brAppFontWithSize + 68
    8   APMB                                0x000000010bb4e145 +[UIFont(SystemFontOverride) systemFontOfSize:] + 37
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010e5e031d -[UIZoomViewController loadView] + 86
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010e191560 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 138
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010e191cd3 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010e5dfcd0 -[UIZoomViewController init] + 82
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010e5dd85e -[UIClassicController _setupWindow] + 582
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010e5dd52b +[UIClassicController sharedClassicController] + 246
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010e0162b5 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 557
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010e015dde -[UIApplication _handleApplicationLifecycleEventWithScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 508
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010dff48a0 __70-[UIApplication scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 159
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010dff452d -[UIApplication scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 843
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010dff2bca -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 591
    20  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001123d32af __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 265
    21  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001123eb8c8 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    22  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001123eb741 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 178
    23  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001123ebaca -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d043301 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d03922c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d0386e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d0380f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    28  UIKit                               0x000000010dff1f21 -[UIApplication _run] + 402
    29  UIKit                               0x000000010dff6f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    30  APMB                                0x000000010bb86e2f main + 111
    31  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001108b592d start + 1
    32  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
```

I am wondering how it is possible that `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is not calling but the view is going to show. And where is the best place to initialize the core data and initialize methods to do not face this problems??

Comment: remove previous app from your simulator or real device and clean build again. Add breakpoint where you adding settings objects in core data . check which key is nil

Comment: The error is probably related to a core data model change, and certainly has nothing to do with universal or not-universal.

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: You are passing `nil` to CoreData.  Put a conditional breakpoint in `BRSettingsRepository getAllRowsInSettings` in order to find it.

Comment: You are right, I found it. It is because the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is not calling in iPad. Please see the recent stacktrace I shared. It is calling on iphone but It is not calling on ipad and I am initializing the repository on that method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found that it is because of `UIFont+SystemFontOverride` class.

I use this class to override system font of my application:

```
#import "UIFont+SystemFontOverride.h"

@implementation UIFont (SystemFontOverride)

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation"

+ (UIFont *)boldSystemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize {
    //return My Custom Bold Font;
}

+ (UIFont *)systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize {
    //return My Custom Normal Font;
}

#pragma clang diagnostic pop

@end
```

it seem that when we are using iPad with `ZoomViewController` the method are calling before `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and the problem was that In implementation of `boldSystemFontOfSize` and `systemFontOfSize` I was using a repository that is initializing at `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`